# How to change half-window shortcuts?

Tags: 12.10

Ubuntu seems to have changed the half-window shortcuts from Ctrl+Alt+NumPad-Numbers to half using the NumPad and Ctrl+Super+Left/Right (which I find absolutely ridiculous). How do I change it back? I can't find it under "Keyboard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from Compiz.

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Launch it from the dash or with `ccsm` and then go to **Grid**

Comment: Package doesn't exist apparently (maybe I'm missing the PPA?), I found the settings manager in software center though. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark, my bad, `ccsm` isn't the package name but the name of the executable. I've made an edit. Glad you found it.